# convert to lambda from rx java expression

Tags: android, rx-java, retrolambda

I've started to grok into retrolambda and rxjava. Some expressions i'v converted by myself, but some of them i can't convert. I've added retrolambda to my project.Here is examples

```
public Observable<ImmutableList<Repository>> getUsersRepositories() {
        return githubApiService.getUsersRepositories(user.login)
                .map(repositoryResponses -> {
                        final ImmutableList.Builder<Repository> listBuilder = ImmutableList.builder();
                        for (RepositoryResponse repositoryResponse : repositoryResponses) {
                            Repository repository = new Repository();
                            repository.id = repositoryResponse.id;
                            repository.name = repositoryResponse.name;
                            repository.url = repositoryResponse.url;
                            listBuilder.add(repository);
                        }
                        return listBuilder.build();
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

But i don't know how to convert this peace of code:

```
obs.subscribe(new Observer<List<Integer>>() {
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("completed");
        }

        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("failure");
        }

        public void onNext(List<Integer> value) {
            System.out.println("onnext=" + value);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that you want to make something like this:

```
obs.subscribe(
         (List<Integer> value) -> System.out.println("onnext=" + value),
         (Throwable e) -> System.out.println("failure"),
         ()-> System.out.println("completed"));
```

You can check [this blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/rxjava-retrolambda/#sthash.e4rHACNL.dpbs) and this example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/HelloRxJavaRetrolambda).

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is an anonymous function and you are creating an anonymous class, similar but different.

First one is already a Lambda: `.map(repositoryResponses -> {...}`, what do you want to change more? The second part is a "block code" so you can't reduce it more.

Second one you can't convert it because it's not a function.

Comment: The first code is ok, i've converted it by myself. I changed
 new Func1<UserResponse, User>() {
                    @Override
                    public User call(UserResponse userResponse) { 
to 
 repositoryResponses -> {}

Comment: What i need is to use it on the second code. If it's not possible it's ok. I'm just asking

Comment: Sure, it's ok, I mean, you can't change it more, Lambda is for anonymous functions only so you can use it for anonymous classes (second code). Ask is ok, you can't keep growing with no asking :)

Comment: Sorry, typo in my previous comment, you **can't** use it for anonymous classes

Comment: I understood, thanks for answer. I found that when it's possible to use retrolambda the compiler is telling it. So it's not suggesting to use lambda on the second code.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the way to solve it. Here is code before conversion

```
    repositoriesManager.getUsersRepositories().subscribe(new SimpleObserver<ImmutableList<Repository>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(ImmutableList<Repository> repositories) {
            repositoriesListActivity.showLoading(false);
            repositoriesListActivity.setRepositories(repositories);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            repositoriesListActivity.showLoading(false);
        }
    });
```

after conversion

```
  repositoriesManager.getUsersRepositories().subscribe(repositories -> {
        repositoriesListActivity.showLoading(false);
        repositoriesListActivity.setRepositories(repositories);
    },throwable -> {
        repositoriesListActivity.showLoading(false);
    });
```

Comment: Hello. Do you know how to auto convert it to lambda code?